# learn-rails bundle install error parsing Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I'm totally noob, and doing the Learn Ruby On Rails Book One from start. I've got stuck a couple of times, but have resolved it myself by google, stackoverflow, etc... (I don't want to be a burden) But this I can't get by.
I'm on the Gemfile "chapter". First I just tried to copy the exact as it is in the book:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org' ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
 # Rails defaults
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0' gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0' gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
 # learn-rails
gem 'activerecord-tableless'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0' gem 'figaro'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
group :development do
gem 'better_errors' gem 'quiet_assets' gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

Which gives me this result:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting gem 'rails', '4.0.1'...https://rubygems.org' ruby '2.0.0'
...                               ^. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/MYUSERNAME/Projects/learn-rails/Gemfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
end 'better_errors' gem 'quiet_assets' gem 'rails_layout'
```

I then tried to change a few things like versions and so on, like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby ’2.3.3’
gem 'rails', ’5.0.1’

 # Rails defaults
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0’
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2’
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks’
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5’

 # learn-rails
gem 'activerecord-tableless'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
group :development do
 gem 'better_errors'
 gem 'quiet_assets' 
 gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

This gives me this result:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot - ruby ’2.3.3’
          ^
/Users/MYUSERNAME/Projects/learn-rails/Gemfile:2: syntax error, unexpected tFLOAT, expecting '('
ruby ’2.3.3’
             ^. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/MYUSERNAME/Projects/learn-rails/Gemfile:2
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  source 'https://rubygems.org'
 >  ruby ’2.3.3’
 #  gem 'rails', ’5.0.1’
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I've tried a few things I found when searching, like changing the ' to " on the ruby version, putting a '0.2.3.3' or just '.2.3.3', doing a bundle update, etc. I don't know what the the "no . floatin..." means? Or what the "expecting '('" is?

I really have searched and tried various solutions (got like 4-5 different saved "Gemfile" from trying whatever I found on the net).
Sorry if this just takes up space in the interwebs, but I just don't get it. If the original (from the book) doesn't even work, then why is it even there?

(I only changed my personal name to MYUSERNAME here, because it's my full, actual name, and maybe I'm paranoid but may so be. So that is not a fault)

Thanks,
Ethonrails

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use `'` not `’` it's a different kind of apostrophe. (Everywhere in your Gemfile, I see a couple of instances `ruby ’2.3.3’`, `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0’`)

Here is a version of your Gemfile that works:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.3'
gem 'rails', '5.0.1'

 # Rails defaults
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

 # learn-rails
gem 'activerecord-tableless'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
group :development do
 gem 'better_errors'
 # gem 'quiet_assets' (not compatible with rails 5 atm)
 gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

Tip: Try to use a code editor with syntax highlighting for Ruby, that should make future syntax errors easier to spot.

Comment: (Ok, I'm trying MacVim, don't like it, but until I find my right one, I just really like the basic text editor, this hopefully looks better)

Thanks. I got somewhere, but I can't paste the output because its too long, stack overflow says.

Comment: Anyhow; the gemfile does not work. It starts a bit like this:
Anyhow; the gemfile does not work. It starts a bit like this:

bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 5.0.1)

Running bundle update does nothing.
Damn it, this looks like sh*t. Why does it not paste it like it shows up in MacVim?

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't worry about pasting the output if it worked. If you're just starting out maybe try something like [Atom](https://atom.io/) or  [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/). If you still need help shoot me an email.

Comment: Oh sorry, we just posted at the same time :) Remove the quite_assets gem for now. It's not compatible with Rails 5.

Comment: My friendly friend! It worked!! I could NEVER have figured that out, your amazing! Thanks so much! Been working on this since morning (8-9 hours).
Do you have any tip on what editor to use that is not MacVim, because I can't get it to copy/paste right here? It looks all messed up...
Again; thanks SO much!
(oh, I'll try Atom or Sublime)

Comment: Happy to help. Again if you're having more issues feel free to send me an email or tweet at me. Starting out is challenging! Everybody has trouble in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace ` characters to '

Comment: I can't see were there is any `, I only see that I use '.

Comment: **wpp** provided the working Gemfile for you. You can copy-paste it. Maybe you could see the difference between ` and ' with another system font.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of back quote (`), use single quote (') in your Gemfile.

As you are learning ruby on rails, I would like to suggest this link which may be useful to you, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html